# Is there a way to prevent dlsym (module, "functionName") every function?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, pkcs#11, dlsym

I have a shared library (more precisely a PKCS#11 module) and I want to write an application that can load a library and use it.

Currently I'm using dlsym like this:

```
My_C_GetSlotList = (CK_C_GetSlotList) dlsym (module, "C_GetSlotList");
if (!My_C_GetSlotList)  printf("Couldn't find function 'C_GetSlotList' in library: %s: %s\n", filename, dlerror ());
```

But the library does have about 68 functions.
I guess the real question is: Do I really have to do this for every functions? Is there a struct with a list of all functions? Maybe I'm just using dlsym wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dlsym() only once to acquire function pointer for C_GetFunctionList() function which will return you structure with pointers to all the other functions.

You can find example code on page 106 in [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](http://pkcs11interop.net/rsa-pkcs11-2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

1. You may just link your app with a shared library and forget `dlsym` completely.
2. You don't have to `dlsym` all 68 functions, but only those ones you really need.

Comment: But i want to be able to use another shared library with the same functions. And in my case I need all the functions.